# Is there a different file-manager available for 13.04?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

I don't really need to make a list of whats wrong with 3.6, cause my guess is, we probably have a identical list.

**question**: *Is there a different file-manager that also writes the desktop, and has similar features like f3 etc... etc..(can I also downgrade from 3.6 to an older nautilus)*

Comment: I voted to close this but, on reflection, the possible duplicate doesn't address "*that also writes the desktop*".

Comment: I'm not sure what 'that also writes the desktop' is referring to.

Comment: Nautilus, at startup, writes the desktop, meaning it displays the icons on the desktop, and also enables you to create files/folder on the desktop. I want to completely remove nautilus. So my next file-manager needs to write the desktop, cause it is gonna be my main file-manager!

Comment: I found two http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-install-nemo-file-manager-in.html | https://launchpad.net/athena-file-manager